# Вставить в таблицу столбец без дублей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Существует таблица:

```
id(int)     name      data

1           name1     12
2           name249   22
3           name855   99
4           name900   64
5           name600   28
```

В столбец "name" нужно вставить новый список имен из другой таблицы, но если в первой таблице имя уже существует, то дубли не вставлять.

Как правильно составить запрос?

Решение:
**Уникальный индекс name и INSERT IGNORE**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`name`) SELECT `name` FROM `table2`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. Отсеять имеющиеся.

```
INSERT INTO table (name)
SELECT name
FROM othertable
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM table
                   WHERE table.name = othertable.name )
```

или аналогичный запрос с JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL.

Вариант 2. Игнорировать попытку вставить дубликат.

Создать уникальный индекс по полю `name` и выполнять вставку запросом INSERT IGNORE - дубли будут проигнорированы и не вставлены.

---

Если уникальность `name` в таблице диктуется предметной областью, то вариант 2 (создание уникального индекса) - единственно правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать по примеру `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM TABLE_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Или `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id
                       FROM TABLE_2)
```

Или `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
   SELECT t1.id,
          t1.name
     FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

[Исходный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513187/4772782)

Comment: А при чём тут поле `id`? автору нужно не допустить дублирования по `name`.

Comment: Верно, нужно вставить уникальные name, не изменяя уже существующие данные в первой таблице.

Comment: @Akina я привел пример реализации, вы можете изменить его под свои нужды. Механизм и варианты реализации я указал в ответе

Comment: Не, просто Вы ответили НЕ на вопрос автора, хотя и дали ему (или ей?) верное направление.